Why there is a relation between the signal wavelength, antenna size and efficient antenna radiation?
For efficient radiation from the antenna, the size of the antenna should be one tenth or more of the signal wavelength.
In B. P. Lathi, Modern digital and analog communication systems,
the following paragraph from chapter 1:

..."for efficient radiation of electromagnetic energy, the radiating
antenna should be one tenth or more of the wavelength of the signal
radiated."


Why this condition needs to be satisfied for efficient radiation?


What you say in your question is not true as far as I'm concerned so, please cite your source.

@Noha, you should put this added detail in your question as an edit. Then, if you want to get the commentors attention, you can "at" him like I did you.

@Andy aka  I have edited the question by adding the reference, and the paragraph taken from the reference

Is that book available on-line? If so then please leave a link. Also, if the antenna is a monopole then you really won't get efficient radiation at half a wavelength hence, the quote (unless substantiated by fuller text) will be untrue.

An electromagnetic wave has decreasing amplitude proportional to the inverse distance (so the power decreases quadratically with the inverse distance).  A pure electric or magnetic dipole field has decreasing amplitude proportional to the inverse of the third power of the distance.
So you really want to involve both electric and magnetic fields, and if the antenna is too short, there is too little displacement current responsible for creating the magnetic component of an electromagnetic field.

I think I used an early edition of this book a very long time ago.
This is a book about signals and systems, and should not be regarded as a good source for information about antennas and electromagnetic fields.
The statement is probably not too far wrong. Small antennas relative to a wavelength are more difficult to design and probably will not work as well, in part because of losses in matching networks. As far as I know there is nothing fundamental about one tenth of a wavelength however.

what do you mean by losses in matching networks? @Fred
